# pyqtSignal() connects bool object instead of str

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Let's say I have this snippet of code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from ui_helloworld import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_hellodialog import Ui_Hi
from sys import argv
from sys import exit


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    update = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.h = HelloDialog()

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_label)
        self.ui.doIt.clicked.connect(self.h.update_label)

    def update_label(self):
        self.h.show()

    def update_label_hello(self, msg):

        self.update.emit(msg)


class HelloDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):

        super(HelloDialog, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Hi()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def update_label(self, msg):

        print msg

        # Crashes the program:
        # TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'
        # >> self.ui.label.setText(msg)


        self.ui.label.setText("Hello world!")


def main():

    app = QApplication(argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    exit(app.exec_())


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

It's fairly simple. It's 2 windows, one is a QMainWindow and the other is a QDialog. The MainWindow has 2 buttons, pushButton and doIt:

- `pushButton` opens the `HelloDialog`
- `doIt` emit the `update` signal

The problem is, that the slot in `HelloDialog` Is receiving a boolean from the `update` signal in `MainWindow`, but I declared it as a str object.

Why does the the `update_label` slot receive a `bool` and not a `str` object?

```
localhost :: Documents/Python/qt » python main.py 

{ push `doIt` object }

False
```

The `Ui_MainWidow` and `Ui_Hi` classes are `pyuic5` generated.

Answer (score 0):

I did not need to connect to `self.h.update_label` directly. I had to connect to the method inside MainWindow called `update_label_hello` to `doIt`, and then connect the `pyqtSignal` to the slot in `HelloDialog`

So, the final result is this:

init of `MainWindow`:

```
def __init__(self):

    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.h = HelloDialog()

    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_label_)
    self.ui.doIt.clicked.connect(self.update_label_hello)

    self.update.connect(self.h.update_label)
```